# bitcoin transaction expired

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-verification

I made a BTC transaction on the 17th of January with this ID:
`1f15277460d80454fae5c3fae60012e9b1b250e16f778b647c6e8e4acc49f1dc`

According to coinify (blockchain.info) it expired, so I wasn't able to exchange the BTC. They responded with:

> Bitcoin transaction was not confirmed on time (this is not your fault or ours, it is the miners who confirm transactions). In such a case, the system issues a refund email. We sent a BTC refund address request to [email]

But if I look up the Tx ID, it seems to be confirmed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

It did indeed process and get verified.

The bitcoin is now in 17rnNNdhnc1dcdb9qBCbMsvHmufFiVzCcJ

If you didn't receive anything in return (goods/services) of value. Then it would seem you've been scammed.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Bitcoin volatile nature of Bitcoin we guarantee the rate for sell orders for 15 minutes. Therefore, if the transaction is not broadcasted by the Bitcoin network (i.e. having at least one confirmation) within the 15 minutes, the transaction counts in our system as expired (which means that we have received the Bitcoin too late to be sure that we can exchange them at the rate given when you have placed your order). When this happens, as we cannot complete the order we have to issue a refund to return you the Bitcoins. To do this we send out an email asking  the customer to enter his Bitcoin address. As soon as we receive the reply with the requested information, we send back the Bitcoins. What you can see when you check the transaction is that it is confirmed , which is true but not fast enough for us to be able to process the order. In order to avoid this in the future we recommend to choose to pay higher transaction fees when sending Bitcoins in order to secure that your transaction has a priority and will be processed in good time. Please know that due to the increased interest in Bitcoin in the past few months transaction fees have increased and by offering higher amount to the Blockchain miners, your transaction will be processed before others. Else, it might be delayed. Thank you for your understanding and collaboration. Best, Coinify

Comment: Thanks, this answer was given to me in an email conversation. Still it's not clear to me why buying bitcoin works different from selling. When buying you offer the exchange rate from the moment the FIAT money arrives. Why isn't there a similar policy with selling BTC?

Comment: Also the block was solved in 15 minutes: `2018-01-17 13:51:06 + 15 minutes` is the minimum time <15 min

Comment: Hello, for more information please contact our customer support at https://help.coinify.com/conversation/new. Best; Coinify